# What's the best quality paper to print night photos?

Tags: printing, long-exposure, night, paper, cityscape

I am shooting numerous different types of long exposures of cityscapes. I want to know what is the best type of paper to print onto? I want to get the deepest blacks.

Comment: Can you define "best" a bit more specifically? Deepest blacks? Most fade resistant?  Easiest size to find a frame for? etc.

Comment: The deepest blacks

Answer (score 1):

> The deepest blacks

The deepest and richest colors, in my experience, come from super glossy papers. So, if you're in the darkroom, go for something like Fuji's RC Glossy crystal archive paper.

If printing at a lab, like mpix, do as @null says and go for the metallic paper.

If printing at home, I'm a super fan of Hahnemühle's Photo Gloss Baryta 320 paper. They also have an RC glossy that might work for your need, but I've no experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

> The deepest blacks

I found that night cityscape images are usually high contrast scenes and that metallic paper adds a lot to the highlights.

This can make the blacks/darks appear relatively deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Metallic paper works well *if* the print will be illuminated properly to allow the illuminating light to bounce off the substrate and back through the ink absorbing layer to give it that "illuminated" from behind" look.

If the print is going to be hung without a decent source of direct lighting in a subdued lighting environment, it can look worse than regular glossy paper.